# How to tell Spock which class to run in specific order

Tags: groovy, spock

Im using Spock for my  tests and I have multiple classes to test. I want to tell Spock to test each class in specific order. Is there a way to do this? I noticed TestNG has got [`@AfterTest`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.13/org/testng/annotations/AfterTest.html) annotation, so does Spock have something similar?

Comment: You mean you have multiple `Specification`s?  Or multiple tests in a `Specification`?

Comment: I have multiple classes that extends Specification

Comment: If your test suite depends on the order of specs and specs depend on the order of feature methods (FM), your test suite is broken. Stay away from that. A spec is to be independent of other specs, a FM is to be independent of other FMs in the same spec. I am an agile coach and in one of my last projects there was a massive Spock/Geb test suite with thousands of tests, and in exactly one very complex Geb integration test we had `@Stepwise` in action because it tested a long page flow including external systems hosted by partners. And BTW, we still felt bad about `@Stepwise`.

Comment: You have 2 separate questions.  One has to do with spec order and the other has to do with `@AfterTest`.  The spec order has been answered below.  "I noticed TestNG has got @AfterTest annotation, so does Spock have something similar?" - You probably want `@AfterClass`.  An alternative is to have a method named `cleanupSpec()` in your spec.

Answer (score 6):

You can't specify Spock test classes execution order. However Spock allows you to specify methods execution order when you add [`@Stepwise`](http://spockframework.org/spock/javadoc/1.1/spock/lang/Stepwise.html) annotation to your test class - in this case Spock will execute all methods in order from top to bottom and if one method fails it will ignore remaining methods in this test class.

> Indicates that a spec's feature methods should be run sequentially in their declared order (even in the presence of a parallel spec runner), always starting from the first method. If a method fails, the remaining methods will be skipped. Feature methods declared in super- and subspecs are not affected.
>
> `@Stepwise` is useful for specs with (logical) dependencies between methods. In particular, it helps to avoid consecutive errors after a method has failed, which makes it easier to understand what really went wrong.

*Reference: http://spockframework.org/spock/javadoc/1.1/spock/lang/Stepwise.html*

```
@Stepwise
class StepwiseExample extends Specification {

    def "first test method to run"() {
        // ....
    }
    
    def "second test method to run"() {
        // ....
    }
    
    def "if previous method failed this one will be ignored"() {
        // ....
    }
}
```

#### Using `org.junit.runners.Suite`

[Jeff Scott Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3533584/jeff-scott-brown) gave a good comment about JUnit's `@Suite.SuiteClasses`. In this case you create a class where you can aggregate your test classes (specifications) into a single test suite and those classes will be executed in the order they have been defined in the suite. Consider following example:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.junit.runners.Suite

@RunWith(Suite)
@Suite.SuiteClasses([
        Test2Specification,
        Test1Specification
])
class TestSuiteSpecification { }
```

This suite executes two specifications `Test2Specification` and `Test1Specification` in the defined order:

[image]

Comment: thanks @Szymon, I already use Stepwise. it runs tests in order that I want but it doesn't run the classes in the order that I want, so I'm afraid this is not what I need. sorry for not being clear.

Comment: @groovierthangroovy This is the only ordered execution you can achieve with Spock. You cannot specify the order of test classes (specifications) as I mentioned in the first paragraph. And basically you shouldn't design your tests to run in specific order - each unit test runs in isolation and it should not depend on side effects from other tests.

Comment: @SzymonStepniak "This is the only ordered execution you can achieve with Spock." - Does a Suite marked with `@SuiteClasses` no longer work?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Thanks Jeff for the comment. You're right, using `@SuiteClasses` might work for the OP. Thx!